# String date sequence is not correct

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I m tring to get the result of string Date in sequence. But the result is all jumbled up. I know I can do this by converting date into DateTime and then use Order By ASC, but in my case I cannot convert it into DateTime.

This is the Query I m using:

```
select (CAST(month(StartDate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(year(StartDate) 
as varchar)) as StartDate 

from ProfileStatsRollup

group by (CAST(month(StartDate) as varchar) + '/' + CAST(year(StartDate) 
as varchar))
```

With this Query, I m getting data as

```
StartDate

2/2014
12/2014
12/2013
1/2016
9/2015
7/2014
1/2014
```

Any clue/help would be appreciated.

Comment: Without an `order by`, you can't expect a consistent ordering. Why exactly can't you order by StartDate?

Comment: Tried order by without converting into DateTime, and that is not working

Comment: What format StartDate is in the table ProfileStatsRollup??

Comment: It is actually in OBDC Standard

Comment: You are casting start date to varchar. What type is it before the cast? If it's datetime just order by it

Comment: @AlanMacdonald Still not working. I m grouping here by month & year, instead of day. So it is the issue.

Comment: However I have solved this issue by separating Columns of Month and Year. Because there isn't any other solution to it.

Comment: Just replace everything from group by down with order by StartDate and leave the select as is

Comment: Thanks @AlanMacdonald. It worked :)

Comment: Although without the `group by`, duplicate month/year combos will not be removed.